# Create a sortable table on the client side using calculated data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a table that displays a name, and two values corresponding to each name that I have calculated using a loop and a progress bar for each value.

The code looks something like this,

```
<table>
<thead>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Value1</th>
<th>Value2</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<% i=0 %>
<% j=0 %>
<% @department.members.each do |members| %>
<td><td><% members.name %><td>
<% members.evals.each do |evals| %>
<% i+=value1 * something %>
<% j+=value2 * something %>
<% end %>
<tr>
<td>
<div class="progress"><div class="bar" style="width: <%= (i*10).round() %>%;"></div></div>
<%= i %>
</td>
<td>
<div class="progress"><div class="bar" style="width: <%= (j*10).round() %>%;"></div></div>
<%= j %>
</td>
<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I wish to allow the user to click the heads and sort this information dynamically without changing the page on the client side, as well as create a drop-down menu above the table that allows the user to do the same. "Sort by value2" and "Sort by value1".

I am using bootstrap, so I don't want to use `DataTables`. Even their bootstrap theme doesn't look like boostrap. I just want a simple sort while preserving my current styling.

Comment: datatable works fine with bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datatable (http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/zero_config.html)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using this with their bootstrap theme.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to sort the table with JavaScript, take a look at [sortable table](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) with jQuery.

You can always edit the CSS file to match your layout or to match with bootstrap's layout.